# useCallback: When to use it? Is there any drawback / performance issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

There are articles related to what is useCallback and to use it when necessary. But in a big project it's very difficult to understand when to start using this.
So, if I use it for every use case, will it hit the performance of the application.

Answer (score 2):

`useCallback` and `useMemo` are helper hooks with the main purpose off adding an extra layer of **dependency check** to ensure synchronicity. Usually you want to work with `useCallback` to ensure a stable signature to a `prop` which you know how will change and React doesn't.

A `function`(reference type) passed via `props` for example

```
const Component = ({ setParentState }) =>{
    useEffect(() => setParentState('mounted'), [])
}
```

Lets assume you have a child component which uppon mounting must set some state in the parent (not usual), the above code will generate a warning of undeclared dependency in `useEffect`, so let's declare `setParentState` as a dependency to be checked by React

```
const Component = ({ setParentState }) =>{
    useEffect(() => setParentState('mounted'), [setParentState])
}
```

Now this effect runs on each render, not only on mounting, but on each update. This happens because `setParentState` is a `function` which is recreated every time the function `Component` gets called. You know that `setParentState` won't change it's signature overtime so it's safe to tell React that. By wrapping the original helper inside an `useCallback` you're doing exactly that (by adding another dependency check layer).

```
const Component = ({ setParentState }) =>{
   const stableSetter = useCallback(() => setParentState(), [])

   useEffect(() => setParentState('mounted'), [stableSetter])
}
```

There you go. Now `React` knows that `stableSetter` won't change it's signature inside the lifecycle therefore the effect do not need run unecessarily.

On a side note `useCallback` it's also used like `useMemo`, to optmize expensive function calls (memoization).

The two main purposes of `useCallback` are

- Optimize child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary
  renders. [Font](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)
- Memoize expensive computing calculations

> Is there any drawback/performance?

`useCallback` is mainly used to optmize performance by changing stuff only when it's needed. It does that by adding a layer of dependencies just like `useEffect` (and similar to how `React` itself knows how something must change in the DOM), but as every single performance optimization technique, it can shoot backwards, if you fill your entire application with unecessary `useCallback`, `useMemo`, `React.memo` the performance will go the other way around.

So the key is to use wisely, carefully choosing what needs to have a stable signature and what doesn't.

Comment: _if you fill your entire application with unecessary useCallback, useMemo, React.memo the performance will go the other way around._ Can you please elaborate this? Why the performance will go the other way around if `useCallback`/`useMemo` is used everywhere?

Comment: Cause each addiotional layer of comparison check costs extra time, if you're memoizing let's say, a `string`, then the comparation to determine rather or not to change it becomes more expensive then just generate a new `string`